# Querying Azure Search from IIS or SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-cognitive-search

It seems easy to apply an `Azure Search` index to an `SQL Azure` database. I undertand that you query the search index using `REST` APIs and that the index then needs to be maintained/updated. Now, consider a web server running IIS, with an underlying `SQL Server` database.

What is considered best practice; querying and updating the index from the web server or from SQL Server, e.g. from within a `CLR` stored procedure? Are there specific design considerations here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on Azure Search team and will try to help. 
Querying and updating the index are two different use cases. Presumably, you want to query the index in response to user input in your Web app. (It is also possible that you have a SQL stored procedure with some complex logic that needs full test search, but that seems less likely).

Updating the index can be done in multiple ways. If you can tolerate updating your index at most every 5 minutes, use Azure Search SQL indexer automagically update the index for you - see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers-2015-02-28/ for details on how to do it. That article describes creating indexers using REST API, but we now have support for that in .NET SDK as well.

OTOH, if you need hard real-time updates, you can update the search index at the same time you produce data to insert / update your SQL database.

Let me know if you have any follow up questions!

HTH, 
Eugene

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! Indeed, user input on the web will need to query the index. There will be other ways to access the database, so I'm considering putting all index querying inside a stored procedure which will then be accessible from both the web and other apps. Is that a realistic/good use case or is it better to query the index directly without involving the database?

Comment: I suspect that querying index directly from the Web apps will be easier and better. Putting that code into an sproc means that all queries will have to make 2 hops: one from Web app to the sproc, and one from sproc to Azure Search. Also, this will increase the load on the database and may interfere with other workloads you use the DB for. Debugging / changing the search code will probably also be more complicated.